# Two different interior cell color give me the same colorIndex VBA

Tags: excel, vba, colors

Why two diffrent cells color give me the same ColorIndex ?

I use this function to get the cell color index:

```
Function InteriorColor(CellColor As Range)
 Application.Volatile
 InteriorColor = CellColor.Interior.ColorIndex
 End Function
```

This is what the function return:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

ColorIndex is limited to 256 Colors, so a broad range of RGB Colors get converted to the same ColorIndex. Use .Color instead, there you are able to use RGB Colors, which are more precise.

```
Cells(1,1).Interior.Color = RGB(255,255,255)
```

Answer (score 1):

`ColorIndex` covers a very limited set of values for a very limited set of colors.

Consider using `Color` instead.